# Reverse scheduled tasks script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

I have run the following .cmd file and I do not like it and want to *completely*
reverse the changes. How would I do this without losing the original information about triggers/conditions etc. ?

```
@echo off



echo press ctrl-c to cancel, enter to continue
pause >nul
echo.
echo.



echo step 5/8: disable scheduled tasks ...
echo.

schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\application experience\aitagent" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\application experience\microsoft compatibility appraiser" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\application experience\programdataupdater" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\autochk\proxy" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\customer experience improvement program\consolidator" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\customer experience improvement program\kernelceiptask" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\customer experience improvement program\usbceip" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\diskdiagnostic\microsoft-windows-diskdiagnosticdatacollector" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\maintenance\winsat" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\activatewindowssearch" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\configureinternettimeservice" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\dispatchrecoverytasks" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\ehdrminit" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\installplayready" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\mcupdate" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\mediacenterrecoverytask" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\objectstorerecoverytask" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\ocuractivate" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\ocurdiscovery" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\pbdadiscovery">nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\pbdadiscoveryw1" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\pbdadiscoveryw2" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\pvrrecoverytask" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\pvrscheduletask" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\registersearch" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\reindexsearchroot" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\sqlliterecoverytask" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\media center\updaterecordpath" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\pi\sqm-tasks" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\power efficiency diagnostics\analyzeSystem" >nul 2>nul
schtasks /change /disable /tn "\microsoft\windows\windows error reporting\queuereporting" >nul 2>nul
echo.

timeout 2 >nul



echo done
pause >nul
```

Comment: Export your scheduled tasks to XML files before enabling all of them if you feel the `/enable` switch as per David's answer below will not retain those other settings in each scheduled task such of the triggers, conditions, etc. http://www.askvg.com/how-to-import-export-backup-restore-tasks-using-task-scheduler-in-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I do not like it and want to completely reverse the changes.

Replace `/disable` with `/enable`

```
F:\test>schtasks /change /?

SCHTASKS /Change [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] /TN taskname
     { [/RU runasuser] [/RP runaspassword] [/TR taskrun] [/ST starttime]
       [/RI interval] [ {/ET endtime | /DU duration} [/K] ]
       [/SD startdate] [/ED enddate] [/ENABLE | /DISABLE] [/IT] [/Z] }

Description:
    Changes the program to run, or user account and password used
    by a scheduled task.

Parameter List:

...

/ENABLE              Enables the scheduled task.

/DISABLE             Disables the scheduled task.
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task. The job can be created on the local or a remote computer.

Comment: Other settings won't change?

Comment: @minusatwelfth Not as far as I know.

Comment: Err, so they won't or will change?

Comment: @minusatwelfth Won't change. Why don't you try just enabling just one of them, then look at settings using the GUI?